# Rails cocoon nested fields, on edit form render existing images next to each field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the `cocoon gem` in order to add attachments to a product. This is the part where I'm rendering the cocoon nested form fields inside the new product form.

```
<div id="attachments">
   <%= f.label :images, required: true %>
    <%= render 'products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
    <% end %>

     <div class="links" id="add_attachment" style="display: inline; float: right;">
       <%= link_to_add_association 'add more images', f, :attachments, form_name: 'form' %>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is the partial:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <span class="control-fileupload">
    <%= form.input :images,:label => "Choose a file", as: :file, :input_html => { class: "file_input" } %>
  </span>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", form %>
</div>
```

All of the above works just fine. The product gets created along with the attachments too.

Now I'm trying to develop the edit a product form where I could edit both the product and the attachments also. Everything works ok with this one too. The only trouble I'm having is.... how to add each existing attachment image to the associated cocoon nested field in the edit form???  Currently only the fields are showing and the user doesn't know which field contains what image so he can make the changes he wishes. I tried the following, the image show correctly on each field but each existing field is rendering twice:

```
<div id="attachments">
   <%= f.label :images, required: true %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |attachment| %>
        <% if @attachments.present? %>
          <% @attachments.each do |attached| %>
            <%=image_tag attached.images_url(:thumb).to_s %>
            <%= render 'retailer_products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
           <% end %>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
          <div class="links" id="add_attachment" style="display: inline; float: right;">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'add more images', f, :attachments, form_name: 'form' %>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `attachment_fields` partial, add these lines to display image

```
<% if form.object.persisted? %>
    <%= image_tag form.object.images_url(:thumb).to_s %>  ## form.object will return your attachment object, from this you can access your image
<% end %>
```

Your existing fields are rendering multiple times because you are rendering the nested fields multiple times in the `each` loop for `attachments`.

Revert your `div id="attachments"` to :

```
<div id="attachments">
   <%= f.label :images, required: true %>
    <%= render 'products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
    <% end %>

     <div class="links" id="add_attachment" style="display: inline; float: right;">
       <%= link_to_add_association 'add more images', f, :attachments, form_name: 'form' %>
     </div>
 </div>
```